# tomcat not starting with xampp

Tags: mysql, tomcat, xampp

I had a problem with mysql in xampp so i decided to reinstall xampp.  I seem to have a problem now with Tomcat.  It is ticked green in the module services column of the control panel however i cannot start it.  It just says "attempting to start Tomcat service".

I also have the following odd symptoms.  I can access a php file in htdocs in my browser.  Predictably the only fault is an error regards the old mysql username not being recognized.  I can also access "localhost/phpmyadmin" where it then warns me of the importance of changing the default password and username.

However i am unable to access "localhost/xampp"; so cannot make these changes.

I am a hobby programmer and asked a question about this problem earlier on today but to no avail.  I have since realized clearly something is up with Tomcat.  Thus therein lies the likely root cause of the problem.

But, to be honest, i was never sure what the hell Tomcat did when i had xampp running fine before.

I would greatly appreciate any help.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

in which os are u working on (linux/windows/...). i've worked on win8 and had similar problem.
Tomcat couldn't start and what i've had to do was add environment variable JAVA_HOME (path to java jdk folder), add it to path variable, and add CATALINA_HOME variable
you can add it trough cmd by using next lines:

```
set "JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03"
set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
set "CATALINA_HOME=d:\usr\apache-tomcat-7.0.27"
```

in first line where stands c:... change it to your directory which contains Java and in third path to directory which contains tomcat, check also if they are the same type, my xampp was x86 and java x64 and it didn't work together so i've installed x86 java

also try to start tomcat using cmd (go to bin folder in your tomcat folder and type startup.bat)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `catalina_start` by double clicking on it. you can find it in the directory in which you have installed Tomcat.
before doing that you might want to run these commands in CMD:

```
set "JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03"
set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
set "CATALINA_HOME=d:\usr\apache-tomcat-7.0.27"
```

Change these commands based on the path of installation of JDK and Tomcat

Comment: How do you know which version of Tomcat he is using?